# CSS Table child not expanding in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

I'm having some issue with a basic CSS Table Layout. My two test cases are Chrome and Firefox.
While Chrome shows the pages as expected, Firefox's child (in example, "inner") div with 100% height does not take up all of the parents height.

I have made a cut down version of the layout, and while suggestions on the overall problem are very welcome, I'd like to note that I would rather not (A) remove the "inner" div, as it is essential or (B) Change any of the table divs that would adversely affect layout without the "inner" div.

html:

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3">
            <div class="inner">
                test
                <div class="inner-bottom">
                    test2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.div { display: table; height: 400px; border: 4px solid #000; width: 300px;}
.div2 { display: table-row; height:auto;}
.div3 { display: table-cell; height:auto; border: 4px solid #f00; }
.inner { height: 100%; border: 4px solid #00f; background-color: #aaf;}
.inner-bottom { background-color:#777; }
```

Screenshot in Firefox : https://mobsoc.co.uk/img/example-csstable-firefox.png
Screenshot in Chrome : https://mobsoc.co.uk/img/example-csstable-chrome.png

As you may note from the images, Chrome correctly fills the available height with its light blue background colour, while Firefox does not.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AqYva/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.div2 { display: table-row; height:inherit;}
.div3 { display: table-cell; height:inherit; border: 4px solid #f00;}
```

Change div2 and div3 heights to inherit from parent to child to subchild.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why auto wasn't good enough? The border was acting right, merely the child that seemed wrong. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: It's just Mozilla's box model and how that applies to tables, table rows and table cells.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

Comment: Well thank you again, that clears a lot more about the issue up!